# HTML5 drag and drop DOM manipulation with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm attempting to reorder DOM SVG elements using the native drag and drop events.  The below code seems to work (with some strange image effects) in Firefox, work a limited number of times in Chrome (2 or 3 drag/drop reorderings work, then it seems to hang), and not very well at all in IE.  My best guess is that there something about the events in question that I'm not thinking about correctly, some type of reset.  Or perhaps using the drag events without dataTransfer this way is incorrect.  My goal is to understand this type of function without libraries, but to have a clearer understanding of DOM functions, JavaScript, HTML, and CSS at the most basic level.  I could easily be wrong anywhere in that list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drag and Drop Experiments</title>
    <style>svg { border-width:3px} </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <svg id="s1" draggable="yes" width="100" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="blue"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg id="s2" draggable="yes" width="100" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="red"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg id="s3" draggable="yes" width="100" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="yellow"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var dragSourceElement = null;
      var dragTargetElement = null;
      function doDragStart(e){
          this.style.opacity = "0.4";
          this.style.border = "solid";
          dragSourceElement = this;
      }
      function doDragEnter(e){
          if(dragSourceElement != this){
             this.style.border = "dashed";
          } 
      }
      function doDragLeave(e){
          if(dragSourceElement != this){
              this.style.border = "";
          }
      }
      function doDragOver(e){
          if(dragSourceElement != this){
              dragTargetElement = this;
              e.preventDefault();//to allow a drop?
          }
      }
      function doDragEnd(e){
          this.style.border = "";
          this.style.opacity = "1.0";
      }
      function doDragDrop(e){
          if(dragSourceElement != dragTargetElement){
          dnd_svg(dragSourceElement,dragTargetElement);
          }
          dragSourceElement.style.border = "";
          dragTargetElement.style.border = "";
          dragSourceElement.style.opacity = "";
          dragSourceElement = null;
          dragTargetElement = null;
      }
      //called after a drag and drop
      //to insert svg element c1 before c2 in the DOM
      //subtree of the parent of c2, assuming c1 is 
      //dropped onto c2
      function dnd_svg(c1,c2){
        var parent_c2 = c2.parentElement;
        parent_c2.insertBefore(c1,c2);
      }
      function addL(n){
           n.addEventListener('dragstart',doDragStart,false);
           n.addEventListener('dragenter',doDragEnter,false);
           n.addEventListener('dragleave',doDragLeave,false);
           n.addEventListener('dragover',doDragOver,false);
           n.addEventListener('drop',doDragDrop,false);
      }
      addL(document.getElementById("s1"));
      addL(document.getElementById("s2"));
      addL(document.getElementById("s3"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note there is a javascript error in your dnd_svg function in IE9. var parent_c2 = c2.parentElement ? c2.parentElement : c2.parentNode; solves it for me. See http://jsfiddle.net/nrNSS/.

Answer (score 0):

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzgAR/10/). There is an issue with drag and drop events on SVG's in FF, so one solution is to add a wrapper element to the SVG. With this, you can use the dataTransfer method and then append the node to the drop location.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    
   <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #div1,#div2 {
                width:350px;
                height:70px;
                padding:10px;
                border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function allowDrop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev) {
                var id = ev.target ? ev.target.id : ev.srcElement.id;
                if (id === "circle") {
                    id = ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
                }
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", id);
            }

            function drop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"
        ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
             <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)"
        ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <br>
        <div id="wrapper" draggable="yes" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
            <svg id="svg" width="100" height="100" draggable="yes" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
                <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="yellow"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

This works for me in both FF 18 and IE 9. The annoying part is that FF and IE both source different targets for these events, with IE returning the SVG as the target for the drag event, whereas FF returns the circle. Very annoying.

Update: I tried this JSFiddle in Chrome 24 and it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks - my main goal was to try and see if I could use the drag and drop events to shuffle the svg elements around, just a simple reordering.  Ultimately, I think the answer may be not to use HTML5 drag and drop for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) is pretty good for understanding native drag and drop, with lots of examples.

However, there might be particular problems associated to SVG. See for example this [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691796): "the dragstart event is not fired on a svg element".

Comment: Hi, thanks, I had reviewed that tutorial when I started this.  But it is a good link.